# How to use protractor to find the fading in content of tooltip generated by Angular-UI?

Tags: protractor, tooltip

I am using Protractor, and trying to find the content of tooltips on the page. These tooltips are generated by Angular-UI, and fading in with moveMouse over them like below. Those tooltips are similar with ng-bind, but I cannot use binding to find them. Also, I tried to getAttribute of this tooltip, but it also didn't work for me, maybe cause protractor cannot detect this element name. Do you have any idea of how to read the content of those tooltips? Many thanks.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" id="label_Merchant_Number"  translate>merchant_NUM</label>
        <input ng-model='searchCriteria.MERCHANT_NUMBER' tooltip="{{'merNumber_tooltip'|translate}}" class='form-control  input-sm'  type='text' id='MERCHANT_NUMBER' name='MERCHANT_NUMBER' maxlength='16' erng-validations>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

we are using getAttribute('tooltip'), works how it should be ...

```
element(by.model('searchCriteria.MERCHANT_NUMBER')).getAttribute('tooltip');
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried again, and it worked. It's weird, it didn't work for me before. Thanks.